# Why does program provide -143155...when I only switched from int to double?

Tags: c, int, double

Why does this code give a completely wrong answer if I use float or double but not int?

```
//C How to Program Exercises 2.33
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
double dailyDrivingCost(double miles, double costPerGallon,double averageMilesPerGallon);
int main(void){
    double a,b,c,d,e;
    printf ("Please enter the number of miles daily\n");
    scanf("%lf",&a);
    printf ("Please enter the cost per gallon\n");
    scanf("%lf",&b);
    printf ("Please enter the average miles per gallon\n");
    scanf("%lf",&c);
    printf ("The number of miles per gallon is:%d",dailyDrivingCost(a,b,c));
getch();
return 0;
}
double dailyDrivingCost(double miles, double costPerGallon,double averageMilesPerGallon){
      double overall_cost;
      overall_cost= (miles/averageMilesPerGallon)+ costPerGallon;

      return overall_cost;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
printf ("The number of miles per gallon is:%d",dailyDrivingCost(a,b,c));
                                            ^
```

to

```
printf ("The number of miles per gallon is:%f",dailyDrivingCost(a,b,c));
```

`d` conversion specifier is used to print an `int`, to print a  `double` (or a `float`) you need the `f` conversion specifier.

Comment: Oh my! Embarrassing. Thank you.